# Secure Online Storage with Mapped Network Drive

Tags: windows, mac, network-drive, online-storage

I am searching for an online storage solution that uses encryption when transferring the data, and when storing the data. I want to be able to map a network drive to the online storage in Windows and Mac. It would be nice to have a mobile app too or at least a web interface. I see there are lots of free choices that don't use encryption when storing the data and that you can map a net work drive with. And I also see that there are options that use encryption when storing the data, but it doesn't look like they support mapping network drives.

This is for personal use. I like the simplicity of having folders and not having the copy my files into an app or some web interface, hence the desire for a mapped network drive. And I want an additional layer of security so that I can feel a little more comfortable with storing sensitive information like banking information and passwords.

I am willing to pay a little, at most $30 a year, though $20 seems more realistic. Not willing to pay more though because my need is not that great. I just want 1 centralized location to store my data.

Comment: I've looked at lots of options and can't find one that does what I want. Didn't research it but I'm guessing this is a limitation of the "Map Network Drive" protocol (WebDAV). Meaning, I'm guessing it's not possible to map a network a drive and decrypt/encrypt files on the fly with WebDAV.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as off-topic, or why it was down-voted twice. I checked the FAQ (http://www.superuser.com/faq) and it says this web site is for "computer software, or personal and home computer networking". Seems like this question falls under both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following all claim to support what I am looking for, that is encrypted transfer and encrypted storage, and also support WebDAV (mapping a network drive):

- _http://www.sharefile.com (too expensive for personal use, min $30/month)
- _http://www.anchorworks.com (required to contact sales for pricing, probably expensive)
- http://www.cloudsafe.com (German-based, 2GB free, 5GB $30/year ...)
- http://www.swissdisk.com (Las Vegas-based, 50MB free, 1GB $4/month ...)

There are tons of companies doing online storage. I am sure there are more options. I haven't tried any yet and can't comment on performance. Will update this post when/if I do.